# How to apply two different CSS on mat-form-field in separate pages?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

I have mat-form-field on one page:-

```
<mat-form-field class="form-control-full-width">
    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="First Name"  formControlName="firstNameFC" required>            
    <mat-error *ngIf="hasNewUserError('firstNameFC', 'required') && isNewUserSubmitted">
               First Name is required
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Following CSS applied:-

```
 .mat-form-field-label {
    /*change color of label*/
    color: white !important;
  }

  .mat-form-field-underline {
    /*change color of underline*/
    background-color: white !important;
  } 

  .mat-form-field-ripple {
   /*change color of underline when focused*/
    background-color: white !important;;
  }

  .mat-input-element{
    color: white !important;
  }
```

CSS is reflecting as expected.

The problem is I have another mat-form-field on different page and want to apply different CSS(color: green, background-color: white) on the field.

Is it possible to apply different CSS on controls in different page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add them in each component's css file like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand your approach but could not able to get the result. I am using style.css. Now i removed those lines and add in login.component.css file. I also added styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'] but it is not reflecting the CSS. Any idea why is it not working? Is there anything more to be done?

Answer (score 0):

yes Its possible just create a separate file called like **textfield.css**

import it in your **style.css** like

```
@import 'globalcss/textfield.scss';
```

put that file in globalcss folder make that folder under src so

**src=>globalcss=>textfield.scss**

now you can take any matInput and just add style like small-text-field see the class added below

```
 <mat-form-field class="small-text-field"> 
              <input matInput placeholder="Username">
            </mat-form-field>
```

and the contents in the textfield.css file goes like

```
.mat-form-field.smallTextfield .mat-form-field-wrapper{
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 125px;
}
```

so in whole application wherever you have matInput if you apply this class it will be added but just note that as of now ng::deep is deprecated use the below directive in the ts file as

**encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None**

this will be used inside

```
@Component({selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None})
```

I hope this is far more better and clear explanation quite understandable as well..!!